# Would NAT be eliminated transformed in ipv6?

Tags: ipv6, nat, ipv4

NAT is a wonderful concept used in ipv4. It is the major reason for the existence on internet, in my concerns. There are no networks in the world that doesn't work without employing NAT.

All I seek to know is that, would NAT be required if after ipv6 is implemented, would NAT be eliminated or be used in a different way(Transformed or Upgraded into a new version with some added abilities to tackle any situations or problems that the network specialists or researchers foresee).

Comment: required, no. Desired, yes quite probably. The primary value to NAT once IP address exhaustion and full-network addressing predictability are eliminated, the remaining value to NAT as we know it now, is Stateful Packet filtering (SPF) firewalls. They allow you to block all unsolicited traffic to a network, but allow solicited responses to connections established within the network boundary. It is likely that SPF is all we really need post-ipv6. Personally, i'm not looking forward to the transition (I like to be hands-on with my networking, and IPv6 really isn't supposed to work that way).

Comment: @FrankThomas, but you can have Stateful Packet filterting without NAT, so that is not really a reason to keep using NAT.

Comment: @FrankThomas, NAT and firewalls are two completely separate subjects which really have nothing to do with each other. There are plenty of production firewalls, even on IPv4, which don't NAT, and they are no less robust or secure than firewalls which also do NAT routing. NAT was put in place to stave off the IPv4 shortage until IPv6 became prevalent, but it breaks the original IP premise of end-to-end connectivity, and we have to jump through hoops to get around that hack. IPv6 will restore end-to-end connectivity.

Comment: agreed. that was the point i appearently failed to make. What most people consider NAT to be, is actually a chain of tools including NAT, PAT, and SPF. Of the three, the only one we really need in a post v4 world is SPF.

Answer (score 2):

NAT is a kludge in IPv4 to get around the IPv4 address shortage while waiting for IPv6 to become ubiquitous. I certainly wouldn't use the word wonderful. NAT breaks the original IP paradigm of end-to-end connectivity, and many workarounds have been needed due to NAT.

IPv6 doesn't have an address shortage problem, and there is currently no NAT for IPv6, although there is an experimental RFC for people who just can't give it up.

Comment: As with [this other answer of yours](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/59438/could-ipv6-make-nat-port-numbers-redundant), could you please point us to where is it said that "the original IP paradigm [is] end-to-end connectivity"? You seem to have strong feelings with NAT but it's just another networking tecnique with various uses...

Comment: That is well documented in RFCs such as the Internet architecture guidelines. "_An end-to-end protocol design should not rely on the maintenance of state (i.e. information about the state of the end-to-end communication) inside the network. Such state should be maintained only in the endpoints, in such a way that the state can only be destroyed when the endpoint itself breaks (known as fate-sharing)._" NAT breaks that principle by requiring intermediate devices to maintain state, requiring a connection to depend on the state of the intermediate devices, rather than only the endpoints..

Answer (score 1):

On home gateways, it should go away, but... it depends.

If your home network gets a /64 subnet from the ISP, you don't need NAT. And ISPs usually get a /32 allocation (even tiny organizations get a /48 by default), so technically they have no reason *not* to give out /64's or even /56's (good enough for 256 subnets per customer) to every single customer they have.

However, I've already heard rumors of ISPs which continue with their IPv4 practice of giving out *only* a single IP address per customer, and selling /64 blocks as an extra feature/addon. So if you end up in that situation, you still need NAT...

Comment: IPv6 doesn't currently have NAT. There is an RFC which is marked as experimental, not for standards track, for NAT on IPv6, but, as of today, NAT doesn't exist for IPv6. IANA originally stated that everyone should get `/48` by default, but softened that position to `/56`. There are enough Global IPv6 addresses in the current allocation of 1/8 the IPv6 address space to supply each of the year 2100 projected 17 billion people with nearly 2100 `/48` networks. There is no reason for NAT on IPv6.

Comment: @Ron: IPv6 doesn't have a _need_ for NAT, nor an "official" spec of NAT, but it _does have NAT_ regardless, because NAT is not an IP feature in the first place –  it's a hack of implementations, and **the Linux kernel _does_ implement both prefix translation _and_ many-to-one NAT for IPv6**.

Comment: But there is no RFC or other standard for NAT on IPv6 as there is for IPv4. Any IPv6 NAT is used at your own risk. The RFCs define the IP standards, including for IPv6. Using NAT on IPv6 is like trying to use multicast on IPv6 and ignoring the standards which have defined Flags and Scopes (which I, unfortunately, see a lot); you may work fine, but you may badly mess something up. There are IPv6 protocols which break with NAT, and there are no workarounds like with IPv4. That's why it is experimental.

Comment: You think ISPs waited for the RFC to deploy IPv4 NAT?

Comment: ISPs are really just now getting around to doing NAT since they can no longer get addresses from the RIRs. It's true that ISPs have only provided a single address for a long time, but IPv4 NAT was released in the RFC in 1994, when the IPv6 RFC was being developed, with the understanding that IPv6 would obviate the use of NAT. IPv6 has built-in security with the optional Authentication Header, and all IPv6 communication can be secured with IPSec using it, but NAT break that, among other problems it creates.

Comment: You're only talking about NAT on ISPs' network itself, but ISP-provided routers are still the ISP's responsibility, even if they're on customer premises...

Comment: You must be very young. ISPs never started providing routers until long after the IPv4 NAT RFC, since the world was using dial-up. The Internet didn't go commercial until 1995, although there were dial-up ISPs before that, and DSL and cable Internet were never rolled out until after the IPv6 specification RFC was released in 1995, the year following the IPv4 NAT RFC. So, to answer your question, "_You think ISPs waited for the RFC to deploy IPv4 NAT?_" in the new context you provided, yes, the ISPs waited until _well_ after the IPv4 RFC to provide NAT to their customers.

Comment: Yes, and it seems I've read the dates on those RFCs wrong as well.